# Initializing the date on a datetimepicker via the model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use the angular date time picker. The problem is that I'm loading the data from the model, the picker doesn't seem to bind the value.

If i just set the value manually to a date, it works, but when it's loaded from the model, it doesn't set the picker to the correct value.

http://plnkr.co/edit/eeTQFo5jz4RYN6nSYxdZ?p=preview

I'm using the http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js datetimepicker for angular.

**angular:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.date = '01/02/1983 01:02:03';
});


app.directive('datetimez', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          element.datetimepicker({
            dateFormat:'dd/MM/yyyy',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
          }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container container-fluid" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  2+2={{2+2}}, var1={{var1}}
  <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate name="form" ng-submit="submit()">
  <div class="well">
    <div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng-model="var1">
      <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text" ng-value="date"></input>
      <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using a string and not a date object:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var date = new Date(1983, 1, 2, 1, 2);
  $scope.date = date;
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5kzPOkOSKn2IVGh6w2R9?p=preview

[I recommend going with MomentJS for shorthand.](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: That doesn't work. The plunker still broken. Also, when I pass the value as a string directly to the value tag, it works (meaning when it's not pulling it from the model). I've updated the plunker to show how the string directly works.